# Visual Studio Code, autopep8 doesn't run

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Windows 10.
I did this:

```
pip install autopep8
```

and in vscode user settings I have

```
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
```

When I run format document, or explicitly invoke autopep8 from the command pallette,  the error is:

```
Error: Command failed: autopep8 c:\tca-backend\lambdas\utilities\NetMenuAPIUtil.py
'autopep8' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Clearly, vsc wants to invoke autopep8.exe but there is no exe.  Just py. So I created a autopep8.bat which works when I test from the command line, but when run from vsc, it inserts the content of the batch file into the top of the document.   (Yes, that's as strange as it sounds.)

All other Python-related operations work ok, including the ESLint extension.

Comment: may need to notice even the `autopep8 is formatting` text is showing (and disappear after a while) at the bottom area of vscode when you trigger the formatting, that doesn't mean the `autopep8` is correctly installed, just make sure you've ran `pip install autopep8`, and retry, this cost me hours of time

Answer (score 15):

VS code Python extension supports source code formatting using either autopep8 (the default), black, or yapf so you don't need to install python formatting tools by yourself.

The way I use formatting is to set a shortcut in vs code.

Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts, then search `format`. Set the shortcut as `ctrl + shift + p` which is the same as the shortcut of autopep8 or you can set any combination you prefer.

[image]

Click the shortcuts in your .py files then you will get the formatted code.

Ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing

Comment: Shift+Alt+F is the default in VSCode for doing this now

Answer (score 4):

I encountered an error message while trying to do same and below was what I did (in my terminal):

1. Install or upgrade pep8:

   pip install --upgrade autopep8
2. Navigate to the folder/directory where the file you need formatted is, then use the following command:

   autopep8 --in-place file_name

There you have it!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using VSCode on Windows, please click on the Terminal Section and type

`pip install pep8`

This will start installing pep8.

Answer (score 2):

for me, the [autopep8 doc](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) installation isn't enough, still seeing this error, I had to follow this https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#user-installs. it works like a charm.

I'm on windows so I used this:

```bash
py -m pip install –-user autopep8
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone encounters this on VSCode, even after properly installing autopep8, configuring the default formatters as others suggested, configuring the keyboard shortcut (though now is default to Shift Ctrl F)...

Try deleting the `.vscode` folder in the current folder entirely, this is what made the document formatter worked for me.

There might be some conflicting parameters inside and causing this nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this as a PATH under System Environment Variables:

```
c:\users\<username>\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages
```

Then close and restart VS Code.  Type autopep8 at a terminal prompt and you should see this:

```
C:\Foobar>autopep8
usage: autopep8 [-h] [--version] [-v] [-d] [-i] [--global-config filename] [--ignore-local-config] [-r] [-j n] [-p n] [-a] [--experimental] [--exclude globs] [--list-fixes] [--ignore errors] [--select errors]
                [--max-line-length n] [--line-range line line] [--hang-closing] [--exit-code]
                [files ...]
autopep8: error: incorrect number of arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same error running WSL: Ubuntu-20.04, well this was my solution:

```
$ pip --version
```

This will make you verify that you have python3 pip installed correctly in your distribution, if that's not the case, it will pop up an error:

```
    Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install python3-pip
```

Just run the indicated command to installed it and then after that, run:

```
$ python3 -m pip install autopep8
```

Now everything should be working as it should, including the formatting autpep8.

Answer (score -1):

The same happened to me, then I just changed the key binding to other keys and it simply worked.