# Auto format flake8 linting errors in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, flake8, linter

I'm using the `flake8` linter for Python and I have many code formats issues like `blank line contains whitespace flake8(W293)`

I'm trying to auto fix these linting issues. I have these settings:

```
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--ignore=E501",
    ],
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
```

I'm using the default `autopep8` formater but it seems that it does nothing.
Nothing happens when I save the file or run the command `Format Document`.

Is there any way to auto fix these linting errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest using a `formatter`, [black](https://github.com/psf/black) for instance, to fix the issues detected by your `linter`.

If so, `pip install` it and add this to your **settings.json**:

```json
"python.formatting.provider": "black"
```

Then, pressing `Alt+ShifT+F` or `Ctrl+S` should trigger the formatting of your script.

Comment: It workes! But I just not understand why the default `autopep8` isn't working...

Comment: Could have something to with how you installed it at first. More on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49783700/11246056

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
 "python.linting.flake8Args": ["--ignore=W293"],
```

And you can switch the formatting to `yapf` or `black`.

If you insist on `autopep8`, you can add this in the settings.json:

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--select=W293"],
```